# Module '"@angular/common"' has no exported member 'NgOptimizedImage'. 3 import { NgOptimizedImage} from '@angular/common';

Tags: angular

The Angular documentation recommends using "NgOptimizedImage" to load images. I followed the instructions but there does not seem to be an NgOptimizedImage export anywhere. When I add the following statement, I get an error. I'm assuming that perhaps NgOptimizedImage is not that useful and has been deprecated, and the docs simply haven't been updated.

```
import { NgOptimizedImage } from '@angular/common';
```

```
Module '"@angular/common"' has no exported member 'NgOptimizedImage'.
```

This all comes directly from the official Angular page:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgOptimizedImage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried to use the NgOptimizedImage directive in a stackblitz and seems to be working just fine.

Are you importing the directive in the module and not your component?

NgOptimizedImage was only added in Angular 14.2 so maybe that's your problem?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qa4mvv) example

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I am on Angular 13 and this is a reminder to upgrade.

Comment: Please, be so kind to accept this answer for people in the future.